# Dynamic component loading in RC5+ using string name parameters

Tags: angular, dynamic-loading

Before RC5 I was loading components dynamically something like this:

```
System.import('path/to/MyComponent')
            .then(fileContents => fileContents['MyComponent'])
            .then(component => {
                this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation(component, ..)
                    .then(() => {
                       ...
                    });
            });
```

Since RC5 this doesn't work because `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated. The problem is its predecessor `ComponentFactoryResolver` takes a type as parameter. I need a way to load components using string names. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it like this:

```
System.import('path/to/MyComponent')
            .then(fileContents => fileContents['MyComponent'])
            .then(component => {
                let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
                this.container.createComponent(factory); //container: ViewContainerRef
            });
```